# How to do case when string not belong to a group then make another column blank?

Tags: sql

Ok so i have 2 columns: Purchaser - Orders

How do I write a case statement to show:

```
case when purchaser is blank, then orders is blank
```

I tried

```
case when purchaser = ' ' then orders = ' ' else orders end as OrdersEnd
```

Comment: So I have a bunch of not valid orders if they don't belong to certain purchasers. And I want to keep the table clean of invalid orders. My current table now has a lot of orders and only some are attached with a purchasers, some have no purchaser.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT
    ...
,   CASE WHEN purchaser = '' THEN '' ELSE orders END AS OrdersEnd
FROM ...
```

Note that "purchaser is blank" could mean "is null or empty". In this case, the syntax should be

```
CASE WHEN purchaser is NULL OR purchaser = '' THEN '' ELSE orders END AS OrdersEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case when purchaser = '' then '' else orders end as OrdersEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

"blank" could mean `NULL` or spaces.  You don't mention the database, but the following should work in most:

```
(case when purchase is null or replace(purchaser, ' ', '') = '' then ' '
      else orders
 end) as OrdersEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for null and a purchaser that has only spaces.

There may be other cases when purchaser is invalid... you can add those in as  more WHEN sections:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN purchaser is null THEN ''
       WHEN TRIM(purchaser) = '' THEN ''
       ELSE orders END as Orders
FROM table
```

Now that I know this is MS SQL this is shorter

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRIM(ISNULL(purchaser,'')) = '' THEN '' ELSE orders END AS Orders
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'blank' means NULL you can get a way with a function specific to DB.

Oracle:

```
SELECT NVL2(purchaser, orders, '') FROM MyTable;
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT IF(purchaser, orders, '') FROM MyTable;
```